# PHP : Add property to object without quotes

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to parse an object with SimpleXML in this way :

```
foreach ($segment->attributes() as $name => $value) {
    $this->{$name} = $value->__toString();
}
```

the result I get :

```
...\Segment {#2203
  +"id": "207"
  +"sequence": "1"
  +"DayOfWeekInd": "2"
  +"CodeShare": "false"
  ...
}
```

My problem is that double quotes are added on the properties names.

I would like to get this instead :

```
...\Segment {#2203
  +id: "207"
  +sequence: "1"
  +DayOfWeekInd: "2"
  +CodeShare: "false"
  ...
}
```

Is there any solution ?

Thanks a lot

Edit :
I'm really confused because when I do some tests, it works well (https://3v4l.org/SknoN) The problem occurs only in the context off the application where i'm working on. (A Laravel app) The problem is probably related to the XML source. I will try to clean it to solve this. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: The quotes are probably encoded the XML, there's no reason PHP would just add them. You can use `str_replace()` or `trim()` to get rid of them.

Comment: Thank you for your time ! I've already tried someting like this : `$this->{trim($name,"\"'")} = $value->__toString();` Doesn't work...

Comment: It works fine: https://3v4l.org/KEJdE I'd run `var_dump($name)` -- it probably doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: `print_r($this);` after the loop.  The quotes are probably just displayed to show that they are strings.

Comment: Hi, please can you [edit] your question to show a [mcve] - include a _small_ sample of XML, some code parsing that, and the way you're testing the result. It's not clear what function is giving you the output you show, and whether the quotes are really part of the object, or just the way that function shows _all_ property names.

Comment: @IMSoP : the output is given by dd function (laravel)

Comment: @Dimitri Are you sure the double-quotes aren't just how `dd` shows object properties? Note that the `var_dump` output in the 3v4l.org post you linked _also_ has double-quotes around the properties, because that's just how they're shown, whereas using `var_export` instead uses single quotes, and `print_r` uses square brackets. I rather suspect you're trying to fix a problem that doesn't exist.